# Strange analytical and numerical results during an integration of a complex integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Mma 13.2.1.0  Win 10 Pro

I am solving the following integral:

```
int1 = Integrate[(E^(I φ) r)/Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 I φ) r^2]*r, {r, 0,R}, {φ, -π, π}, Assumptions -> R > 1]
```

with the outcome:

```
1/4 (-I R^2 + π (-1 + R^2) + 2 I R^2 Log[R])
```

However the integral

```
int2 = Integrate[(E^(-I φ) r)/Sqrt[-1 + E^(-2 I φ) r^2]*r, {r, 0,R}, {φ, -π, π}, Assumptions -> R > 1]
```

evaluates to exactly the same expression. These two integrands are complex conjugated. However, the integration results are equal.

*For one thing, it looks for me as a bug*.

For the other thing, I need the result.

I tried to solve it numerically:

```
NIntegrate[(E^(I φ) r)/Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 I φ) r^2]*r, {φ, -π, π}, {r, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> #] & /@ {"LocalAdaptive", "GlobalAdaptive","EvenOddSubdivision"}
```

Returning

```
(* {1.24345*10^-14 + 4.44089*10^-16 I, -1.31465*10^-8 - 
  3.64292*10^-16 I, -1.31465*10^-8 - 3.64292*10^-16 I} *)
```

along with a lot of warnings (except for "LocalAdaptive") like "Numerical integration converging too slowly" and alike. This numerical result does not look very convincing for me.

**Any idea for a workaround?**

Comment: I don't find your `int1` and `int2` bugs. These are improper double integrals which are not calculated by direct use of Newton-Leibniz formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both integrals are improper because of two integrable singularities

```
Reduce[-1 + E^(2 I \[CurlyPhi]) r^2 ==  0 && \[CurlyPhi] > -Pi && 
\[CurlyPhi] <= Pi && r > 0, \[CurlyPhi]]
```

> `r == 1 && (\[CurlyPhi] == \[Pi] || \[CurlyPhi] == 0)`

In order to calculate `int1` two small disks of different radii centered at these singularities should be excluded from the domain of the integration and then passing to the limit should be done. Being lazy, I exclude an annulus `Annulus[{0,0},{1 - eps,1 + eps}]` with `eps > 0` to this end. Now

```
int11 = Integrate[(E^(I \[CurlyPhi]) r)/
Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 I \[CurlyPhi]) r^2]*r, {r, 0,  1 - eps}, 
{\[CurlyPhi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]
```

and

```
int12 = Integrate[(E^(I \[CurlyPhi]) r)/
Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 I \[CurlyPhi]) r^2]*r, {r, 1 + eps, R}, 
{\[CurlyPhi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < R - 1 && R > 1]
```

produce long outputs which are omitted. Next,

```
Limit[int11 + int12, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> R > 1]
```

> `1/2 (-\[Pi] + \[Pi] R^2 - 2 I ArcSinh[1] + 2 I R^2 ArcSinh[R] +  I Log[-1 - I] - I Log[-1 + I] - I Log[1 - I] + I Log[1 + I] -  I Log[2 - Sqrt[2]] + I Log[2 + Sqrt[2]] +  I R^2 Log[I - R - Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] + I R^2 Log[R - Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] - I R^2 Log[I + R - Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] -  I R^2 Log[-I - R + Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] -  I R^2 Log[R + Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] +  I R^2 Log[-I + R + Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] +  I R^2 Log[1 + R - Sqrt[1 + R^2]] +  I R^2 Log[1 - R + Sqrt[1 + R^2]] -  I R^2 Log[-1 + R + Sqrt[1 + R^2]] -  I R^2 Log[1 + R + Sqrt[1 + R^2]])`

and

```
 int1= FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> R > 1]
```

> `1/2 R^2 (\[Pi] + I ArcSinh[R] - I Log[I + R - Sqrt[-1 + R^2]] -  I Log[2 R (1 + I R + I Sqrt[-1 + R^2])] +  I Log[(-I + R + Sqrt[-1 + R^2]) (-1 + R - Sqrt[1 + R^2])] +  I Log[-I (-I - R + Sqrt[-1 + R^2]) (1 + R - Sqrt[1 + R^2])])`

The above result differs from yours. Let us verify `int1` numerically by

```
  int1/. R -> 10.
```

> `0. + 0. I`

and

```
NIntegrate[(E^(I \[CurlyPhi]) r)/Sqrt[-1 + E^(2 I \[CurlyPhi]) r^2]*
r, {\[CurlyPhi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 10}, Method -> #, 
   Exclusions -> {-1 + E^(2 I \[CurlyPhi]) r^2 == 
  0}] & /@ {"LocalAdaptive", "GlobalAdaptive",  "EvenOddSubdivision"}
```

> `{0.0000122805 + 2.22045*10^-16 I, -5.5682*10^-11 +  2.16165*10^-11 I, -1.31465*10^-8 - 5.27356*10^-16 I}`

together with several warnings and errors. I don't know good numeric methods for multiple improper integrals. I leave `int2` on your own.

Addition. Up to a constant multiplier the integral `Integrate[(E^(-I φ) r)/Sqrt[-1 + E^(-2 I φ) r^2]*r,  {φ, -π, π},Assumptions->r>0]` is nothing but a contour integral

```
ContourIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1 - z^2], z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, r], 
 Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[0, r <= 1]`

Also

```
 ContourIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1 - z^2], z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, r], 
 Assumptions -> r > 1]
```

> `0`

To be sure,

```
ContourIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1 - z^2], z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 3],  WorkingPrecision -> 12,PrecisionGoal->6,AccuracyGoal->6]
```

> `3.85954244598*10^-14-2.48320221365*10^-13 I`

Comment: Thank you. I understand.